# Find scaled image width and height in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to know how we find the width and height of a scaled image in cocos2d. I tried the following way to find but, it didn't work,

To find width : self.spriteimage.position.x * scaleFactor

Answer (score 0):

The position.x is not the width. To get the width try:

```
self.spriteimage.contentSize.width * scaleFactor;
```